# Best practices for reporting from many different databases

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

Hi I have 14 locations and i'm going to start creating reports for the 14 locations.  We do replicate some information with our POS companies software (customers, giftcards and pre-paid cards) however not all information such as sales and labor are replicated.  This means when running my reports I need to hit all 14 databases to put them into readable format... Does anyone have any suggestions or best practices for something like this?

Answer (score 5):

If you're in a position to be able to set such a thing up, this sounds like an excellent candidate for a data warehouse:

- Set up a large central database that is not used for transaction processing
- Optimise the schema(s) of this database purely for reporting
- Draw in periodical feeds (overnight feeds being a popular option) from each of the 14 source databases
- Run reports to your hearts content across the data from all 14 databases in one go

Comment: Any suggestions or documentation on how to move forward with this?

Comment: It's Oracle docs, but they cover a lot of the concepts and there's some nice architectural-type pictures to go with it: [Data Warehousing Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96520/concept.htm)